# if..else statement in the c++ standard

Tags: c++, if-statement

From the C++ standard section 6.4.1: **The if statement**:

> If the condition (6.4) yields true the first substatement is executed. If the else part of the selection
>   statement is present and the condition yields false, the second
>   substatement is executed. In the second form of if statement (the one
>   including else), if the first substatement is also an if statement
>   then that inner if statement shall contain an else part.

Section 6.4: **Selection statements**:

```
Selection statements choose one of several flows of control.
    selection-statement:
        if ( condition ) statement
        if ( condition ) statement else statement
    condition:
       expression
       attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer-clause
       attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator braced-init-list
```

I thought that **else if() {}** statement was a separate statement from **if() {}** and **else {}**.
Now it seems that this **else if {}** statement is just an else statement with it's own **if() {}** inside it so these two codes are equal:

```
if(condition) {

    }
    else {
        if(condition) {

        }
    }

if(condition) {

    }
    else if(condition) {

    }
```

Now what if we have multiple else if-s? These codes are also equal in C++:

```
if(condition) {

    }
    else {
        if(condition) {

        }
        else {
            if(condition){

            }
        }
    }

if(condition) {

    }
    else if {

    }
    else if {

    }
```

About the last code: When we write an else statement without curly braces only the first statement is associated to the **else** because the other statements are not part of that **else**(they are not in curly braces with the first statement). So isn't it logical for the compiler to say that the second **else** is not associated with an if statement?

Comment: Technically there's no separate `else` statement, it's an optional part of the `if` statement.

Comment: I know that and I wrote that in my post above. My question is at the end of my post.

Comment: You quoted the corresponding syntax yourself: `if ( condition ) statement else statement` so I am not sure what you are asking, each else is the else of an if, so which else do you think is wihtout any if?

Comment: It isn't "logical for the compiler" to say that the second else is not associated with if statement - because it is associated. Try to use else without an if.

Comment: What else would it be?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to ask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (condition) statement else statement
```

is a single *selection-statement*. This means that the entire `if...else` is the substatement of a previous `else`.

or in other words, you start rolling up the statements from the bottom.

Comment: "This means that the entire if...else is the substatement of a previous else." - Thanks. That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The `else` is part of the `if` statement it corresponds to. In the case of:

```
if(condition) {

}
else if {

}
else if {

}
```

The nested statements are as follows:

```
if (condition) { } else // first statement
  if { } else           // second statement
    if { }              // third statement
```

So the second `else` is associated with the second `if`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for these rules is to resolve a problem known as the [Dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.

It rears its head in code like this...

```
if (A) 
if (B) DoB();
else DoC();
```

When is `DoC()` performed?  Does it happen when `A` is `false`? Or does it happen when `A` is `true` and `B` is `false`?

There is no *logical* way for the compiler to resolve this kind of situation.  So outside the normal parsing rules, 6.3 declares that in this ambiguous case, the else belongs to the *inner* if statement.

Comment: I am not sure what is your point. The first if doesn't have an else, and the else statement is associated with the second if. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the problem.

Comment: So, as @Sebastian Redl said, the entire if-else is a substatement. Here it's a substatement to the first if statement. If it was as I thought before, then there would have happened this problem. Very nice answer, thanks for pointing this.

Comment: Clarifying this (false) ambiguity is precisely why most coding rules recommend to always use braces with if statements. Current GCC issues a warning with that code.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't logical for the compiler to say that the second else is not associated with an if statement.